# In Visual Studio 2008, is there a way to create and managing css and html code snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know of a way to add css and html code snippets to Visual Studio 2008?

I love my C# snippets, and HTML/CSS snippets would save a ton of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply mark a piece of HTML/CSS code and drag it into the toolbox. Then rename the snippet in the toolbox and give it a name so you can easily remember what it is.

Then just drag&drop it from the toolbox onto another page to insert the snippet.

(Maybe first create a separate group in the toolbox for your snippets).

Comment: Nice tip - never knew you could do that.

Comment: Ive just noticed toolbar is often disabled whilst debugging, annoying.

Comment: Is there a way to make this do surrounds with ?